# The setColumn can only replace the first column

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

when i try to delete an item from the column and return the new column, the setColumns replace only the first column, the data in the column is correct but  the placement is wrong

this is the initial state
[image]

this is the result expected after deleting the item

[image]
this is the result after calling the delete function

[image]

The new in progres column does  show the wanted  outcome but it didn’t replace the right column

How can i make it work properly?

this is the code for this app

```js
const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
      

    useEffect(() => {
        props.fetchOrder(setOrders)
        
    },[])

 
    const columnsFromBackend = {
        newOrder: {
            name: "Requested",
          items: orders,
          },
        inProgres: {
            name: "In Progres",
            items: [],
          },
        finished: {
            name: "Finished",
            items: [],
          },
        deliverd: {
            name: "Deliverd",
            items: [],
          },
    } 
const [columns, setColumns] = useState([])
console.log(columns);

    useEffect(() => {
        setColumns(columnsFromBackend);
        console.log("test");
    }, [orders]);;
```

i thinks the problem is with the useEffect hook that calls setColumns for the first time but I’m not sure.

this is the code for the delete function

```js
const deleteItem = (item, columns, column, setColumns, index) => {
    const itemId = item._id
    const columnsArray = columns
    const copyColumns = [...column.items]
    console.log(typeof(copyColumns));
    copyColumns.splice(index, 1);
  
   console.log(columnsArray)
   setColumns({
           ...columns,
           ["newOrder" || "inProgress" || "finished" || "delivered"]:{ 
            ...column,
            items:copyColumns
    }});
    dispatch(deleteOrder(item));
};
```

this is how I  render the columns

```js
 {Object.entries(columns).map(([_id, column]) => {
                    return(Objects)
                    }
```

this is the parameters that I passed to the delete function

```js
const deleteItem = (item, columns, column, setColumns, index) => {}
```

how can I make  the code return the column to the right position?

Comment: You should provide expected result and what you're getting. It's not clear now what the problem is.

Comment: This line `["newOrder" || "inProgress" || "finished" || "delivered"]:{ ` should be this `[column]:{`

Comment: @Simas.B
I have updated my question hope it will be  more understandable

Comment: could you update your question with how you render columns, ant what parameters you pass to delete item function. Ideally you could post a minimal reproducible code sample.

Comment: @Simas.B
I have updated my question  again, i added what  you asked for

Comment: your columns state object is an array but here`setColumns({ ...columns, ["newOrder" || "inProgress" || "finished" || "delivered"]: ..column, items:copyColumns }});` you're assigning it as an object. Also keep in mind when changing a state array you should always pass the previous state of the arraye i.e. setColumns(previousColumns => { //your mutations here}

Answer (score 0):

I  was able  to make my code work, it isn’t  best practice but it’s works.

i needed to refer to each column key so to each column  object I have added a property `columnNumber`, and each individual column got a different number
and anew key that much the property  `columnNumber`

```js
 const columnsFromBackend = {
        
        1: {
            columnNumber: 1,
            name: "Requested",
          items: orders,
          },
        
          2: {
            columnNumber: 2,
            name: "In Progres",
            items: [],
          },
          3: {
            columnNumber: 3,
            name: "Finished",
            items: [],
          },
          4: {
            columnNumber: 4,
            name: "Deliverd",
            items: [],
          },
    }
```

in the delete function I have added `const columnNumber = column.columnNumber`

so i have a verbal to use in the setColumns function

this is the setColumns function

```js
setColumns( prevState => {
       return{
        ...prevState,
        ...columns,
            [columnNumber]: {    
                columnNumber: columnNumber,   
                name: column.name,
                items:copyColumns}
         }      
       })
```

and it works the results are returned as expected